# How to switch language from English to Arabic so that it can be read right to left?

Tags: android, multilingual, arabic-support

While Switching language from English to Arabic, the layout is changing from left to right. How do I change the textView from left to right. 
Example (English) Ramesh driving with a speed of 34kmph. 
(Arabic) hpmk43 fo deeps a htiw gnivird hsemaR

Edit 1: Please find the below image is it correct?

[image: Arabic version]
[image: English Version]

Comment: That's not how RTL languages work. English words are still read left-to-right.

Comment: You're looking to reverse the order of the string shown. Your example is not Arabic, you need to give a little more details about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`setLocale("en");`//set English

`setLocale("ar");`//set Arabic

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
```

will automatic RTL after set locale as English and LTR set locale as Arabic. 
//Don't forget to restart your app. after set locale

> No need to change gravity

Answer (score 1):

To make your `TextView` work for RTL, you should add layout properties of RTL.

Use `android:layout_marginStart` in place of `android:layout_marginLeft`
and
`android:layout_marginEnd` in place of `android:layout_marginRight`

For `left-to-right` flow, `start=left`, `end=right`.

For `right-to-left` flow, `start=right`, `end=left`.

This RTL support was added in API Level 17, as part of Android 4.2's support for RTL layouts.
This will help you
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#RTL

Answer (score 0):

Change all of your app's `left/right` layout properties to new `start/end` equivalents.

Simply example, use in  `android:gravity`.

Don't forget to declare in your app `Manifest` that your app supports RTL mirroring: add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the element in your `Manifest` file.